# Compilation of CMSIS-DSP application, .a library not recognized

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, arm, cmsis

I am using GNU MCU ECLIPSE and the ARM toolchain to target CortexM MCUs, and I want to use functions from CMSIS DSP library.
I have downloaded the library from the repository from https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5, added to the compiler settings the paths to the includes, and in the linker options I have added the folder C:/workspace/CMSIS/DSP/Lib/GCC as path to search for libraries, and added 'arm_cortexM3l_math' to the libraries.
When I try to build I get the error

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"C:\workspace\eclipse_tools\CMSIS_5-develop\CMSIS\DSP\Lib\GCC" -Wl,-Map,"hello6.map" --specs=rdimon.specs -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lc -lm -lrdimon -Wl,--end-group -o "hello6.elf"  ./src/main.o   -larm_cortexM3l_math
c:/workspace/eclipse_tools/arm embedded gcc/8.2.1-1.7-20190524-0603/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:C:\workspace\eclipse_tools\CMSIS_5-develop\CMSIS\DSP\Lib\GCC\libarm_cortexM3l_math.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/workspace/eclipse_tools/arm embedded gcc/8.2.1-1.7-20190524-0603/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:C:\workspace\eclipse_tools\CMSIS_5-develop\CMSIS\DSP\Lib\GCC\libarm_cortexM3l_math.a:1: syntax error
```

I don't understand why can't the linker read the library in .a format. I have tried with a clean eclipse installation both on windows and linux and with both the GNU MCU Eclipse ARM Embedded GCC and the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain.
Build tools for windows are also correctly installed.

Comment: What does the "file" command say is the type of libarm_cortexM31_math.a?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that, despite those files look like libraries, they were kind of a placeholder, as they were just few bytes. I then downloaded and unpacked the CMSIS packs from here:
https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/cmsis/cmsis-packs
(Submenu ARM->CMSIS)
and the same files now work.

So I guess they were not compiled yet? But there was no makefile in the repository, how was I supposed to build them?

@andy mango, thanks, the file command indeed returned just 'ASCII text file'